# Test Base Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a SessionsController which all other controllers in my application inherit from. I want to test both base controller methods.

The create rspec works fine, I call "post :create" because there is a route setup. The 2nd method "require_session" is a different story, there is no route. Instead we call this method as before action. What are some approaches I can take to test the require_session method?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_session

  def create
   #...
  end

  def require_session
    #...
  end

  def not_authorized
    render json: "Not Authorized", status: 401
  end

  def server_error
    render json: "Server Error (code 1)", status: 500
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about invoking `SessionsController` and calling it on that:

```
sc = SessionsController.new
sc.require_session
```